# Callback not executing

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm new to asynchronous programming and I've been trying to understand callbacks. I'm having trouble understanding what I've done wrong? The callback simply doesn't run.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/movies');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connected to mongodb.');

    var movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        release_date: Date,
        cast: Array
    });

    movieSchema.methods.AddMovie = function AddMovie(callback) {
        console.log(this.title);
    };

    var Movie = mongoose.model('Movies', movieSchema);

    var revenant = new Movie({
        title: 'The Revenant',
        release_date: new Date('2015-12-25'),
        cast: ['leonardo dicaprio']
    });

    var callback = function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else console.log(data);
    }

    revenant.AddMovie(callback);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `revenant.AddMovie` and you pass in the `callback` function you defined. You define `AddMovie` further up and you accept the `callback` as an argument, however you don't ever actually call it. You appear to just be logging the movie title to the console when `AddMovie` is invoked. You don't actually do anything with the passed in callback function.

```
movieSchema.methods.AddMovie = function AddMovie(callback) {
  console.log(this.title);
};
```

In there you need to actually call the callback function. Something like this:

```
movieSchema.methods.AddMovie = function AddMovie(callback) {
  if (someError) return callback(someError);
  callback(null, data);
}
```

I wrote [this post](http://codetunnel.io/what-are-callbacks-and-promises/) back in the day when I too was struggling with callbacks and asynchronous code. Give it a quick read. I try to use very simple examples.

Comment: Thanks for the link and great job on the post!